# Prove this for any $k>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, factorial

Prove that $k!>(\frac{k}{e})^{k}$.

It is known that $e^{k}>(1+k)$. So if we multiply $k!$ on both sides, we get $k!e^{k}>(k+1)!$. Also $k^k>k!$. Now how to proceed ?

Answer (score 4):

I take it that $k$ is a positive integer. Then the question is equivalent to

$e^k>\frac{k^k}{k!}$

But $e^k=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{k^n}{n!}$ and one of the summands (all of them are positive) is itself $\frac{k^k}{k!}$

Answer (score 2):

Work by induction.

- For $k=1$ it is true as $e >1$
- Assume it is true for $k$. Then $(k+1)! = (k+1) k! > k k!> k \frac{k^k}{e^k} = e \frac{k^{k+1}}{e^{k+1}} > \frac{k^{k+1}}{e^{k+1}}$ because $e>1$.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I cannot comment so I'll share my thought here: [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

Comment: You need a rep of $50$ in order to leave a comment.